# C++ classes with members referencing each other

Tags: c++, pointers, c-preprocessor, class-design

I'm trying to write 2 classes with members that reference each other. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or it's just not possible. Can anyone help me out here...

**Source.cpp**

```
#include "Headers.h"
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    Network* network = new Network();

    system("pause");
    return;
}
```

**Headers.h**

```
#ifndef Headers_h
#define Headers_h

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Network.h"
#include "Router.h"

#endif
```

**Network.h**

```
#include "Headers.h"

class Network
{
protected:
    vector<Router> Routers;
};
```

**Router.h**

```
#include "Headers.h"

class Router
{
protected:
    Network* network;
public:
};
```

The errors I'm getting are:

> error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
>       error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
>       error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed.

I'm pretty sure I'm not missing any semicolons or stuff like that. The program works find if I take out one of the members. I tried finding similar questions and the solution was to use pointers, but that's what I'm doing and it does't seem to be working!

Comment: You have two files trying to #include each other, which isn't good...

Comment: Side notice - You need to specify namespace for vector in your header file ( `std:vector <Router>`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first error - you need to explicitly use the namespace:

```
std::vector<Router> Routers;
```

Don't "use namespace std;" in header files

Other errors are restulting from the first :)

As to the referencing to the class defined later, you need to do forward declaration of Router class, put

```
class Router;
```

into your Network.h

Comment: I took out the vector member and changed it to `Router* router;` and added the forward decleration in Headers.h. But still no luck.

Comment: Thanks, your fixed answer fixed the problem for me. I needed to add the forward decleration in Network.h and not Headers.h. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You need the full definition of `Router` in order to define an `std::vector<Router>`.  A forward definition of `Network` in `Router.h` would be appropriate, however.

Answer (score 4):

1. Use [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).
2. Use [Forward declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration)

E.g.

**Source.cpp**

```
#include "Network.h"
// using namespace std; // bad idea unless it's a quickie test program

void main()
{
    Network* network = new Network();

    system("pause");
    return;
}
```

**Network.h**

```
#ifndef MY_NETWORK_H_INCLUDED
#define MY_NETWORK_H_INCLUDED

#include "Router.h"
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
// even better is:
//     typedef std::vector<Router> t_RouterVec;
//     t_RouterVec routers;

class Network
{
protected:
    vector<Router> Routers;
};

#endif // MY_NETWORK_H_INCLUDED
```

**Router.h**

```
#ifndef MY_ROUTER_H_INCLUDED
#define MY_ROUTER_H_INCLUDED

class Network;

class Router
{
protected:
    Network* network;
public:
};

#endif MY_ROUTER_H_INCLUDED
```

**VERY BAD IDEA**
I consider this to be a smell. You're making everyone include everything. Now every time you change something in Network.h or Router.h you have to recompile (and ideally re-test) everything!

```
#ifndef Headers_h
#define Headers_h

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Network.h"
#include "Router.h"

#endif
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried the include guards before. They did not work so I used a common headers file that has an include guard. As for the forward decleration, that works for me. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to prefix your vector with `std::`. Your other option is to put `using namespace std;` at the top of that file.

```
std::vector<Router> Routers;
```

or

```
using namespace std;
...
vector<Router> Routers;
```

Comment: Please do not use `using namespace std`, *especially* in a header file, since it will pollute any other file that includes it.

Comment: @TheBuzzSaw I caught that just before you posted, but that did not solve my problem. I tried changing the member to `Router* router;` but it still does not work. Same error.

Comment: @Peter I was not implying that he should put it in the header file.

Comment: @SaadImran. See the other answers. You are attempting to have two header files include each other. Resolve that first.

Comment: @TheBuzzSaw I got forward decleration to work for me. However, I can't see how two header files are including each other, curious to know. Can you point that out for me? Thanks.

Comment: `Headers.h` is including `Network.h`, and `Network.h` is including `Headers.h`. Generally, don't have an "omniheader" that just includes all the things. Keep the classes isolated as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

**Compilation issues:**

1. Please add std:: before vector in Network.h
2. Please Correct main to return an integer, as per standards.

---

**Circular References:**

`Network.h` references class `Router` for its vector contents and Router.h references
class `Network`. This is a chicken an egg scenario. You can't have both :).

To resolve this I would recommend the following:

1. Add an opaque class reference Network in Router.h.

   Since `Router.h` uses a pointer to a Network, it doesn't need to know the details of Network, it just needs to know that network is a class.

   class Network;
2. Change the order of the include directives in `Headers.h` to be

   #include "Router.h"

   #include "Network.h"