# Interdependent struct declaration

Tags: c++, struct, declaration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When to use forward declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-to-use-forward-declaration)
>   [C++ classes with members referencing each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140713/c-classes-with-members-referencing-each-other)

I am pretty new to C++, and I have a question regarding two structures defined below as shown below. Each struct contains a pointer to the other:

```
    struct A{
    ...
        ...
    B *ptr;
}

    struct B{
    ...
    ...
    A* ptr;
};
```

However, since the 2nd structure is defined only after the first, I get a compilation error. Is there a solution for this? I tried to declare the struct separately in header files, but it didn't work. Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Just forward declare `struct B` before `A`, meanwhile I will find the duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++ in order to have a pointer to a type you don't need complete definition of that type. You can just forward declare it.

```
struct B;
struct A {
    ...
    struct B* ptr;
};
struct B {
    ...
    struct A* ptr;
};
```

Comment: @JohnDibling "forward declaration" & "declaration" are equivalent in respect to classes.

Comment: Turned out to be quite simple! Thank you all, appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use a forward declaration:

```
struct B;  //forward declare B
struct A{
    ...
        ...
    B *ptr;
};

struct B{
    ...
    ...
    A* ptr;
};
```

Since the members are pointers, a full definition isn't required - a declaration is sufficient.